# Subordination principle

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $f,g:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ so that $f(0)=g(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1=g(1)$, $f$ is increasing and $f'$ is decreasing in $[0,1]$ and that $g(x)\le f(x)$ for $x\in[0,1]$. Can we conclude that $$\liminf_{x\to 1} g'(x)\ge f'(1),$$ provided that $g$ is $C^1$ differentiable at $(0,1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. E.g., let $f(x):=\sqrt x$ for $x\in[0,1]$,
$$g(x):=\sqrt{x} \Big(1-(1-x) \sin ^2\frac{1}{1-x}\Big)$$
for $x\in[0,1)$, and $g(1):=1$.

Then for natural $k$
$$g'\Big(1-\frac1{(k+1/4)\pi}\Big)
=\frac{-(4 \pi  k+\pi )^2+8 \pi  (4 k+1)-12}{4 \sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{4 k+1} \sqrt{4 \pi  k+\pi -4}}\sim-\pi k\to-\infty$$
as $k\to\infty$.

So,
$$\liminf_{x\uparrow 1} g'(x)=-\infty<\frac12=f'(1).$$

---

Here are the graphs $\{(x,f(x))\colon0\le x\le1\}$ (blue) and $\{(x,g(x))\colon0\le x\le1\}$ (gold):

[image]